# Calculating Percentage in symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, formula

I'm trying to calculate a percentage of a filter against a total number and show in symbology so total number 583269 (Plots) formula is  "Column A"  > -123 (gives a result of 582962) I would like to show what the percentage of that result against the total so it should be read 99.947%

Comment: Using which software?

Comment: i'm using QGiS 3.34.0-Prizren

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total of the filtered values by using the `sum` function and its optional `filter` argument. Get the overall total by applying the `sum` function with no filter:

```sql
sum("Column A", filter:= "Column A" > -123) / sum("Column A") * 100
```

Comment: Thanks  i will give it a go